# HTML select tag is not getting populated after fetching the data and changing the state

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the following code which should render the dropdown with a list of values once the data is fetched. I used a state value `loading` to make the re-rendering work.

However, it does not re-render the dropdown after fetching the data. I tried some options which I found on StackOverflow using the `useEffect`, but it makes my code run into an infinite error loop.

Below is the code:

```
//necessary imports
function Home(props){
     const [role_options, setRoleOptions] = useState([]) 
     const [is_loading, setIsLoading] = useState(true)
     const set_roles=()=>{        
        let temp_data = []
        Promise.resolve(get_roles()).then(value=>{ 
        value.map((x,i)=>{
        let eachx = {key:i,text:x,value:x}
        temp_data.push(eachx)})                
       })      
       return temp_data    
       }
      useEffect(()=>{
        setRoleOptions(set_roles());   
        setIsLoading(false) ;
      },[])   
      if(is_loading === true)
         return ('Loading......')
      return(
          <ul className="dropdown-menu">
             {role_options.map((role,i)=>{
                 <li key={role.key}>{role.text} {role.value}</li>
              })}
         </ul>
      )
}
export default Home
```

I would also like to add that the above code works if I just change the `<ul>, <li>` to `Dropdown` from `semantic-ui-react`. I have also tried `<select>, <option>` HTML tags that also do not work. If I add `role_options` as a dependency inside the `useEffect` like below:

```
useEffect(()=>{
    setRoleOptions(set_roles());   
    setIsLoading(false) ;
  },[role_options])
```

This makes my code run into an infinite loop. Could anyone please tell me what will be the solution to what I am doing wrong here?

Also, this component is called in the `App.js` file of React as one of the many components, and this `Home` component is the first one which is called when the page loads after `npm start`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use your `useEffect` like below, with an empty dependency array. I assume `get_roles` is an asynchronous function, according to how you used it.

```
function Home(props) {
  const [role_options, setRoleOptions] = useState([]);
  const [is_loading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);

  useEffect(() => {
    get_roles().then((value) => {
      const temp_data = value.map((x, i) => ({ key: i, text: x, value: x }));
      setRoleOptions(temp_data);
      setIsLoading(false);
    });
  }, []);

  if (is_loading === true) return "Loading......";
  return (
    <ul className="dropdown-menu">
      {role_options.map((role, i) => {
        return (
          <li key={role.key}>
            {role.text} {role.value}
          </li>
        );
      })}
    </ul>
  );
}
export default Home;
```

Your attempt is not working because `temp_data` is returned before the promise is resolved. And another error, you are not returning anything in your `map`.